# sending email with images in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

when we researched on how to send email with images we found two options.

1. we can embed the images in the email as attachments

or

1. we can specify the url to the image so that it downloads the image from the server when the message is viewed.

I am curious to find out which option is better and which one will be used by most of the people.

Answer (score 3):

I would say use links, don't embed, don't attach.  (If you can help it -- maybe some special case will be an exception, but generally speaking...)

For one, email size is an issue -- you don't want your emails to be larger than necessary, both for your own server's sake, and also for whatever limitations your recipient may have.

Also, embeded images look like spam, and attachments will sometimes be blocked / removed before the email is delivered.

**EDIT**
This is interesting -- having to do not just with images, but html in general.  Not to advocate for plain-text (because I perfer to use HTML in most cases), but food for thought, anyway: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/why-bother-with-plain-text-emails/

Answer (score 1):

I always use the URL approach, as I think it is nicer for the user.  It doesn't clog up their email and it gives them the choice of whether they want to download the image.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but I think that attachment is more preferable.

I recommend you to rely on a framework. MvcMailer could work with attachments easily:

https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Answer (score 0):

If you enable HTML for email body and use image tag, I think looks better.